# Jquery not working on external JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a custom dropdown menu that works perfectly fine when I add the script on the main html file but when i link it from an external JS file, the function seems to act faulty. It is not showing output.

This is the Script

```js
$('.tc-navigation > a').click(function() {   
    var element = $(this).parent('li');
    element.children('ul').toggleClass('toto');
    return false;
});
$(document).click(function() {
    $('.tc-navigation > li > ul').removeClass('toto');
});
```

Do Jquery functions like `parent()`, `children()`, `siblings()` stuff like that work on an external JS file? If not, is there a way to make them work?

Comment: Could you show us how you're importing the file?

Comment: <script src="js/external.js"></script>

Comment: The name of the file is external.js. It is situated in js folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you loading your JavaScript file before the DOM is rendered?

Try the defer attribute:

```
<script src="js/external.js" defer></script>
```

> **defer:**
>
> This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before firing DOMContentLoaded.

Answer (score 3):

You need to load first jQuery, later your functions. With jQuery you can wait until the dom is loaded and rendered also.

`parent()`, `children()`, `siblings()` functions will work fine in an external file.